# stddev and avg of 2 tables oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I have 2 tables in Oracle SQL Developer: movies and movie_types.

Table 'movies' containing values: movie_id, movie_title, movie_qty, movie_value, and movie_cat_id.

Table 'movie_types' containing values: movie_cat_id and movie_category.

How can I display the movie_title, movie_category, and then the movie_qty greater than movie_qty by at least 1 standard dev of all movies' movie_qty?

This is for a homework question, the question itself sort of confuses me and I cannot find a similar example.

Here is the table data:

```
CREATE TABLE movie
(movie_id number(2),
movie_title varchar2(40),
movie_qty number(2),
movie_value number(2),
movie_cat_id number(2));

CREATE TABLE movie_types
(movie_cat_id number(2),
movie_category varchar2(30));

INSERT INTO movie VALUES(1, 'Alien', 5, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(2, 'Bladerunner', 3, 8, 1);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(3, 'Star Wars', 11, 15, 1);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(4, 'Texas Chainsaw Massacre', 2, 7, 2);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(5, 'Jaws', 1, 7, 2);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(6, 'The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly', 2, 7, 3);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(7, 'Silverado', 1, 7, 3);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(8, 'Duck Soup', 1, 5, 4);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(9, 'Planes, Trains, and Automobiles', 3, 5, 4);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(10, 'Waking Ned Devine', 4, 12, 4);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(11, 'Deep Blue Sea', 3, 14, 5);
INSERT INTO movie VALUES(12, 'The Fifth Element', 5, 15, 5);

INSERT INTO movie_types VALUES(1, 'SciFi');
INSERT INTO movie_types VALUES(2, 'Horror');
INSERT INTO movie_types VALUES(3, 'Western');
INSERT INTO movie_types VALUES(4, 'Comedy';
INSERT INTO movie_types VALUES(5, 'Drama');
```

And I have tried:

```
select movie_category, movie_title,
(avg(movie_qty)),
(stddev(movie_qty))
from movie, movie_type
where movie_type.movie_cat_id = movie.movie_cat_id
group by movie.movie_cat_id;
```

I know that is wrong, if anyone can offer some guidance I would appreciate it greatly! Thanks in advance let me know if clarification is needed.

Comment: It would help, if you [edit]ed the question and included the result wanted with the given data as a text table (check the markup manual for a how-to) instead of just a (vague) description.

Comment: Why are there duplicate movie types? Why does your table have no constraints (primary key, unique or foreign keys)?

Comment: @MT0 ahh I added the wrong table values, that was from a something I was testing earlier, editing it now. As far as constraints, for this homework they weren't absolutely required so I didn't put any. I do not fully understand constraints so I didn't want to mess anything up. I am definitely beginner!

Comment: This is what you probably what you want for constraints [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cea01d0acb4195c6084e34c6e8e44d9a).

Comment: You can't have tables in SQL Developer, that's just a client tool (a graphical interface through which you can access the database), not a database product.

Comment: In your attempt, you seem to try to get the movies that have "qty" greater than average **for the category** plus the stddev **for the category**. In your explanation in words there is nothing about "separately for each category" - so please clarify, which one is correct? I assume it's "separately for each category" - otherwise there would be no point in looking at the other table - but please confirm.

Comment: @mathguy it was never clarified in the problem, however I believe it would be separate for each category.

Comment: Well - before you can do your homework, you would do best to ask the instructor for clarification, since that point is crucial.

Comment: The question asked here says "of **all** movies' movie_qty?" assuming that the OP has copied the entire question correctly then the window for calculating the mean and standard deviation would be the entire result set rather than calculating for each category.

Comment: @MT0 - obviously the OP did **not** copy the entire question correctly. The words "average of" are clearly missing from this part (copied and pasted): ***the movie_qty greater than movie_qty by at least 1 standard dev of all movies' movie_qty*** A "qty" can't be greater than **itself** plus a positive quantity (std dev). Interesting that none of the responses took **that** part literally, and instead referred to the code, which is the only place that mentions "average".

Comment: @mathguy The title mentions average and stddev.

Comment: @mathguy sorry, I meant 'movie_qty greater than the average of movie_qty by 1 stddev', it's been a long day, lol. I just emailed my instructor for a bit of clarification on the question itself though.

Answer (score 0):

As this is homework.

It can be done using [analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html). Your query is almost there, you would just need to convert the aggregation functions to analytic functions by removing the `GROUP BY` clause and adding an `OVER (...)` clause to change it to an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT movie_category,
       movie_title,
       movie_qty,
       AVG(movie_qty)    OVER () AS avg_movie_qty,
       STDDEV(movie_qty) OVER () AS stddev_movie_qty
FROM   movie
       INNER JOIN movie_types
       ON movie_types.movie_cat_id = movie.movie_cat_id
```

Would output the category, title and quantity for each movie and the average and standard deviation `OVER` a window across the entire result set.

Then you would need to take it a step further and wrap it in an outer query which would filter the rows adding a `WHERE` clause to compare the quantity to the average plus one standard deviation. I'll leave that for you to complete.

---

The alternate way of doing it is to take your query, again without the `GROUP BY` clause and add a filter to compare the quantity:

```sql
SELECT movie_category,
       movie_title
FROM   movie
       INNER JOIN movie_types
       ON movie_types.movie_cat_id = movie.movie_cat_id
WHERE  movie_qty > ( ... )
```

Then, in the braces you can put a sub-query that calculates the average of the quantity plus one standard deviation across the entire result set (note: you will not need a `GROUP BY` clause if you are calculating it across the entire result set).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e0abe2b2df0a4578dccd0ee273124c9a)*

Answer (score 0):

An old-school way is to calculate the STDDEV in a subquery.
Since it'll only be 1 result, you can cross join to it without worry.

```
SELECT movie_category, movie_title, movie_qty
-- , stddev_movie_qty
FROM movie
JOIN movie_types
  ON movie_types.movie_cat_id = movie.movie_cat_id
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 
     STDDEV(movie_qty) AS stddev_movie_qty 
   FROM movie
) stats
WHERE movie_qty > stddev_movie_qty
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=107b15f48de0355660b857a7c1ca12e6)*